# Virtualized AutoComplete Error - Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(ListboxComponent)`

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

The Autocomplete Virtualization example at https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#main-content produces and error in the console advising:

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(ListboxComponent)`, expected a ReactNode.

Does anyone know what the error is referring to? The example works but I'd like to know where the error is coming from to better understand the example

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be coming directly from line 109-111 where the the propTypes of children are specifically being defined as node (Typechecking). Because children is not a node, the error is thrown.

```
ListboxComponent.propTypes = {  
      children: PropTypes.node,
};
```

If these lines are commented out, the error goes away; but, are the children supposed to be nodes? It would seem they should be per these lines being added to ensure such but then why is it working without. Does anyone know of any documentation/articles explaining this example in a little more depth?